# Help on a homework question finding the area of a curve using polar equations

Tags: integration

Show the area enclosed by $r=a(p+qcos\theta)=\dfrac{2p^2+q^2}{2}\pi a^2$.

Due to the form of the equation, the curve is either a cardioid or an egg shape - either way, the boundaries of the integral used to find the area will be $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\pi$.

$A=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_\alpha^\beta r^2d\theta$

$A=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^\pi a^2(p+qcos\theta)^2d\theta$

$A=\frac{a^2}{2}\int_0^\pi (p^2+2pqcos\theta+q^2cos^2\theta)d\theta$

$A=\frac{a^2}{2}\int_0^\pi(p^2+2pqcos\theta+\frac{q^2}{2}cos2\theta+\frac{1}{2}$

$A=\frac{a^2}{2}[p^2\theta+2pqsin\theta+\frac{q^2}{4}sin2\theta+\frac{1}{2}\theta]_0^\pi$

Since $sin0=0$

$A=\frac{a^2}{2}(\pi p^2+\frac{\pi}{2})$

There are now no values of q present, so I can't get it into the form required. Have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to multiply by $q^{2}$ when decomposing the term $\cos^{2}\theta$. As well, notice that at the end you have to multiply the area by 2 as you are only finding the area under the curve of the upper half of the cardioid.